# Relationship with 2 custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, slug

i want to relation to custom post types.

I register post types with this code

```
add_action('init', function(){

$args = array(
  'public'             => true,
  'query_var'          => true,
  'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => '/' ),
  'supports'           => array( 'title', 'excerpt'),
  'query_var'          => true,
  'label'              => 'Series'
);
register_post_type('series', $args);

$args = array(
  'public'             => true,
  'query_var'          => true,
  'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => '%series%', 'with_front' => false ),
  'supports'           => array( 'title', 'excerpt'),
  'query_var'          => true,
  'label'              => 'Episode'
);

register_post_type('episodes', $args);

});
```

I have a serie named "Game of Thrones" it's work like this

> http://wordpress.dev:8888/game-of-thrones

Also i have a episode named "Test", and i want to relation like this

> http://wordpress.dev:8888/game-of-thrones/test

How can i do this? Thank you, and sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: [Link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51386/many-to-many-relationship-between-two-custom-post-types) Check out this link . This is what you want

Answer (score 0):

I did not use this personally, but judging by the description, this plugin should solve your problem:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/

Happy Coding,

Kuchenundkakao

Comment: thank you for answer :) i'm handle relations with this, but slugs doesn't work .

Answer (score 0):

I'm solved with this code;

```
add_filter('post_type_link', function($link, $post){
    if ($post->post_type != 'episode')
        return $link;
    if ($cats = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'serie_slug', true))
        $link = str_replace('%serie%', $cats, $link);
    return $link;
}, 10, 2);

add_action('init', function(){

$args = array(
  .
  .
  'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'series' ),
  .
  .
);
register_post_type('series', $args);

$args = array(
  .
  .
  'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'series/%series%', 'with_front' 
  .
  .
);

register_post_type('episodes', $args);

flush_rewrite_rules();

});
```

You must be add `serie_slug` (must be same named serie) as post meta to episode. You can do this manually or using metaboxes.