# Storing a many to many post type relationship in post meta and keeping SQL ability for Joins

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta, array

I have 2 Custom Post types and i am manually keeping a relation between them in a many to many relationship by keeping an array as a custom field.

All PARENT post types have ONE filed in wp_postmeta which is an array and contains all the post_id's from the child post types.

Arrays in wp_postmeta is serialized, so that means that i cannot access my data directly and only from SQL as MYSQL doesn't know about PHP serialization.

Since i need N children related to every parent post type, how i would store a many to many realtionship BUT also preserve the ability to make JOINs in SQL level?

[THIS](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51386/many-to-many-relationship-between-two-custom-post-types) SO question although describes very well the many to many relationship it uses the approach of a serialized array.