# Two Custom Post Types Many to Many Relationship

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, custom-field, post-meta

I am trying to achieve many to many relationship between two custom Post Types. This is exactly my problem: [many to many](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51386/many-to-many-relationship-between-two-custom-post-types), but the solution seems to be very complicated, and actually I can't manage to run it properly. I would like to write as simple solution as possible and achieve this:

Custom Post Types: **Movies** and **Actors**.

I would like to choose **Actor** trough Metabox while creating **Movie**.
I would like also to choose **Movie** trough Metabox while creating **Actor**.

I know that there isn't any native solution for that (or maybe is?). What are the necessary parts only to run it properly?

I don't want to use any third party plugins.

Thx!

Comment: How about using a custom taxonomy that you'd assign to both the post types? Have you tried/considered that?

Comment: It's a complicated problem, so you're either going to need a solution that's as complicated as that, or a plugin, but you've ruled out both...

Comment: @SallyCJ Yeah, I was thinking about that but this solution seems to be a bit limiting. Or maybe I am doing it wrong.. I will try once again.

Comment: @JacobPeattie yeah.. I am looking for a less complicated solution. But maybe there isn't such one.